# Unexpected end of declaration message occurred while using AIDE in android, why?

Tags: java, android, aide

I am using AIDE in android. It give me message several time when I use correct code as well. What is the problem in it?

```
package com.mycompany.listview;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.text.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();

myList.add("khan");
myList.add("Gul");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrays=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code into `onCreate()` callback:-

```
ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();

myList.add("khan");
myList.add("Gul");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrays=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
```

put it like this:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

    ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();

    myList.add("khan");
    myList.add("Gul");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrays=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
}
```